# Next.js, SanityCMS link issue - all page is link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, content-management-system, sanity

if I open link which go outside app and use back button in browser then if click on every space on page this link is opening. How it works this way? How to fix it?

Example:
https://www.infele.pl/projekty/projekt/meritum-forest
https://www.infele.pl/blog/post/parametry-utm-czym-sa-i-jak-ich-uzywac

It occurs only in SanityCMS content, on other pages like
https://www.infele.pl/oferta/projektujemy/yellowgray
Outside links works correctly

Have a wonderful day!

I've tried to manipulate  component used with/without passHref, but the behavior is still the same.